# Gradle plugin-specific dependencies

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to implement a plugin with optional user-provided dependencies, for example like some Gradle other plugins allow to:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    // ...
    dokkaPlugin(libs.dokka.versioning.plugin)
}
```

I managed to create a `configuration` in the project with name `myPlugin`:

```kotlin
val config = project.configurations.create("myPlugin")
```

So now, in client projects using my plugin I can do:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    myPlugin("com.example:example:1.0.0")
}
```

The question is: how to apply my configuration to run some java code with classpath containing `myPlugin` dependencies?

Here is some more code for context:

```kotlin
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        val extension = project.extensions.create<MyPluginExtension>("myPlugin")
        val config = project.configurations.create("myPlugin")

        val task = project.tasks.register<MyTask>("myTask") {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

class MyTask : DefaultTask() {
    @TaskAction
    fun execute() {
        val config = project.configurations.getByName("myPlugin")
        // How to run some java code using this config?
    }
}
```

I understand that during compile time of my plugin these client-provided dependencies won't be available, so I won't be able to use classes from `com.example:example` directly. But I still want to create some instances using reflection or get them using `ServiceLoader` API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Configuration` extends `FileCollection`, so it's a wrapper around a group of files. You can resolve that configuration when you are ready and add it to a classpath.

##### Running as a separate Java program

Gradle has a built-in task [JavaExec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) that you can use to create your own tasks executing Java programs.

So you can register a new task and configure it with all the same items you would add as if you were running a `java` command from the command line:

```
tasks.register<JavaExec>("myRunTask") {
    args("something the program needs to know")
    classpath(
        theJarsWithTheCompiledCodeOfMyProgram, // Build this in a separate project
        myNewConfiguration // Defined in the plugin for user's use
    )
    mainClass.set("the.main.clazz")
}
```

To get your hands on `theJarsWithTheCompiledCodeOfMyProgram`, you can create a additional subproject `MyPluginApp` to your plugin in a [multiproject project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html); and specify the `MyPluginApp` JAR as a dependency of the project the plugin is applied in using `MyPluginApp`'s Maven coordinates, ensuring that the target project has access to a repository with that JAR in it (or it is in the same Gradle build).

##### Within the plugin

If that all seems like too much, alternatively you can run everything within the plugin by resolving your new configuration and using the resulting files to create a new [URLClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) instance and load what you need from them.

Such code would be triggered from the `@TaskAction` method of task you define.

Comment: How to create `theJarsWithTheCompiledCodeOfMyProgram` with the program being built as a sibling subproject?

I managed to do it the following way:
`classpath(project.buildscript.configurations.getByName("classpath"), config)`
given that the plugin is on build script class path. I wonder is there a way to narrow down `project.buildscript.configurations.getByName("classpath"),` to the classpath of the plugin itself?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend resolving the buildscript classpath in that way. I've explained some more options for you in the answer.

Comment: I am afraid I still didn't get your suggested approach. If I add a configuration to plugin build script (`configurations { create("myPluginApp") {} }`) it won't be accessible inside plugin code. And if I resolve it "to a file" in my build script, then the plugin won't be usable outside the parent project.

Comment: So I managed to do the following:
 - create a configuration `myPluginApp` in the plugin code (not build script)
 - programmatically add a `myPluginApp` dependency to the `project`
 - now I have two configurations which I can use to run my app from the plugin.

One trick should be done though to execute a version of the my-plugin-app matching the version of my-pluign. For that I used an approach you suggested: save plugin version to the file in resources during build and use this version during step 2 to specify the app version. What do you think?

Comment: I agree that the originally suggested approach was not viable for a published plugin. I have amended to show an approach with putting in the Maven coordinates (which is what I think you are also talking about). I think this is the "right" way to do it :)